# Object Model to identify customers with similar address

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table of customers and each customer has an address.  My task is to design an object model that allows to group the customers by similar address. Example:

1. John 123 Main St, #A; Los Angeles, CA 90032
2. Jane 92 N. Portland Ave, #1; Pasadena, CA 91107
3. Peter 92 N. Portland Avenue, #2; Pasadena, CA 91107
4. Lester 92 N Portland Av #4; Pasadena, CA 91107
5. Mark 123 Main Street, #C; Los Angeles, CA  90032

The query should somehow return:

```
1 Similar_Address_Key1
5 Similar_Address_Key1
2 Similar_Address_key2
3 Similar_Address_key2
4 Similar_Address_key2
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? Notice the addresses are NOT consistent (some address have "Avenue" others have "Av" and the apartment numbers are different). The existing data of names/address cannot be corrected so doing a GROUP BY (Address) on the table itself is out of the question.

I was thinking to add a SIMILAR_ADDRESSES table that takes an address, evaluates it and gives it a key, so something like:

```
cust_key  address                                        similar_addr_key
1         123 Main St, #A; Los Angeles, CA 90032         1 
2         92 N. Portland Ave, #1; Pasadena, CA 91107     2
3         92 N. Portland Avenue, #2; Pasadena, CA 91107  2
4         92 N. Portland Av #4; Pasadena, CA 91107       2
5         123 Main Street, #C; Los Angeles, CA 90032     1
```

Then group by the similar address key. But the question is how to best accomplish the "evaluation" part.  One way would be to modify the address in the SIMILAR_ADDRESSES table so that they are consistent and ignoring things like apt, #, or suite and assign a "key" to each exact match.  Another different approach I thought about was to feed the address to a Geolocator service and save the latitude/longitude values to a table and use these values to generate a similar address key.

Any ideas?

Comment: The zip code looks promising.

Comment: SQL itself cannot do such automated evaluation, almost sounds like machine learning. You as the user must browse the table data and find patterns. Then query those patterns to match to originals. Most RDMS have regex functions and of course the `LIKE` operator with wild cards.

Comment: When you do a like statement you could use _ as a wildcard.  The problem you are facing however is not a simple solution - in fact it becomes very difficult to say 'what is similar'.  This is one of the many inherit issues of dealing with data.  Similarity is a matter of computational comparisons from many angles.  Since the computer can not think you generally result to pattern matching. Pattern matching is a weak approach to comparing similarities. A better approach is to split the address into it's components and evaluate by selecting where like and using one or more criteria.

Comment: Furthermore if you are actually attempting to locate addresses within a zone you should retrieve their geodata via a service like google geocode https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro - this will allow you to gain the latitude and longitude of the location and from there you can do radius math within your queries to select properties within a specified distance from around a single point.  I don't know what the problem you want to solve is but N. Portland Ave could exist in every city in America. Is that really a similarity? Or just a common occurrence? Hard to say.